# I created an LSPA job using policejob and now I can't store weapons into the armory. I get the following error

Tags: datastore, inventory, fivem

I created an lspajob using policejob and it mostly work but one of the bugs I found was this error:

[script:esx_datastore] SCRIPT ERROR: @esx_datastore/server/classes/datastore.lua:34: attempt to
index a nil value (local 'obj')

[script:esx_datastore] > ref (@esx_datastore/server/classes/datastore.lua:34)

[script:esx_datastore] > ref (@esx_lspajob/server/main.lua:265)

[script:esx_datastore] > handler (@esx_datastore/server/main.lua:66)

[script:esx_datastore] > ref (@esx_lspajob/server/main.lua:264)

[script:esx_datastore] > TriggerServerCallback (@es_extended/server/functions.lua:160)

[script:esx_datastore] > handler (@es_extended/server/common.lua:121)

[script:esx_datastore] SCRIPT ERROR: error object is not a string

[script:esx_datastore] (nil stack trace)

this happens every time I try to store a weapon into the armory and I can't seem to figure out why. Can anyone help? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you create the entry on your table "datastore" for the job LSPA ?

```
INSERT INTO datastore (name, label, shared) VALUES ('lspa', 'Los Santos PA', 1)
```

If no, do this and normaly after server restart, you don't have issue anymore.